# PHP: http_build_query multidimensional array with empty keys

Tags: php

I am trying to create the following output with the PHP function `http_build_query()`:

```
xyz[abc][]=someValue
```

So the first approach was as easy as it gets:

```
$params = ['xyz' => ['abc' => 'someValue']];

echo http_build_query($params); // Outputs: xyz[abc]=someValue (urlencoded ofc)
```

But I failed when I tried so many approaches to put the second `[]`, that I am at  a point where I do not know further. My plan is not to write a new function since I usually use PHP common functions as much as I can. But if it is not possible I am glad to see some possible solutions for my issue.

Thanks in advance :)!

Comment: `['xyz' => ['abc' => ['someValue'] ] ]` should be sufficient? Edit: Nevermind it addes an index...

Comment: You should try ['some'Value']

Comment: @Scuzzy No, because this would output `xyz[abc][0]=someValue`. I really need an empty array here, since the API that I am using requires that.

Comment: Then I'd suggest manual building of the string or post processing of the string. (Eg find and replace with a regex.

Comment: Well then you either _will_ have to write your own function, or replace those `[x]=` occurrences back to just `[]=` using a regular expression or something. (If you only ever needed _one_ of those, then `['' => 'someValue']` would do the trick - PHP allows the empty string as an array key, but using that you could obviously not have more than one element in that array.)

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help @Scuzzy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestion in regards to "post processing" of the string with preg_replace().

This looks for `[n]` and replaces it with `[]`

```
$params = ['xyz' => ['abc' => ['someValue'] ] ];

$query = preg_replace( '/%5B\d+%5D/','%5B%5D', http_build_query( $params ) );
```

or

```
$params = ['xyz' => ['abc' => ['someValue'] ] ];

$query = urlencode( preg_replace( '/\[\d+\]/','[]', urldecode( http_build_query( $params ) ) ) );
```